# How does RxFire handels firestore queries

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, rxfire

This js reduce works fine to handle the query result:

```
function toc(current) {
  return {....};
};
function getToc(data) {
  return = data.reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.id]: toc(c)}), {});
};

const query = db.collection(normCollection)
.where('a_id', '==', a_id )
.where('year', '==', year) 
.orderBy("id");
subscriptionNorm = collectionData(query, "id")
.subscribe(data => console.log(getToc(data)));
```

But when I use RxJs reduce, it stops working. It has something to do with the stream end, but ... But I do not understand how RxFire / RxJs handles a streamed firestore query result:

```
...
subscriptionNorm = collectionData(query, "id")
.pipe(reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.id]: toc(c)}), {}))
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Update this works fine, but ...:

```
...
subscriptionNorm = collectionData(query, "id")
.pipe(
  map(v => v.reduce((a, c) => 
    Object.assign(a, {[c.id]: toc(c)}), {})
  ),
)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct about the rxjs reduce operator.

> "Applies an accumulator function over the source Observable, and
> returns the accumulated result when the source completes" - from the docs, see here: [RxJS reduce docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce)

In your case source won't complete because that's how Firestore works, it is running endlessly without completion, until error happens or you unsubscribe manually.

For a rough example, you could use `take(1)` operator inside the pipe and it will complete the source Observable after emitting 1 event, thus the `reduce` will work, **but it kills the main idea behind the Firestore Observable.**

**This is the way you can utilize rxjs `reduce` operator:**

```
subscriptionNorm = collectionData(query, "id").pipe(
  switchMap(data => from(data).pipe(
    reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, { [c.id]: toc(c) }), {})
  )),
).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

This is possible because I am switching to the `from(data)` and the inner Observable will get completed, thus the `reduce` operator will work as you intend.

**But, to be honest that's an overkill and you could simply keep the way you already have implemented**:

```
subscriptionNorm = collectionData(query, "id").pipe(
  map(data => data.reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, { [c.id]: toc(c) }), {}))),
).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: So i can't use reduce here. Really? Take(1) is not an option.

Comment: Ah sorry, you do can use the rxjs reduce, I just explained the reason why it's not working currently as it is. I will edit the answer to show your updated code with the reduce